# Spring Boot web app w/ both session + CSRF & stateless Basic Auth w/o CSRF

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, csrf, basic-authentication

I'm trying to stand up a Spring Boot based web server that supports both a secured session-based UI, including CSRF protection and stateless access that is authenticated via basic auth and does not require CSRF.  The two use cases I'm trying to support are a standard AngularJS UI and a simple REST api that authenticates on every request.

Does anyone know how to configure this?  I've seen lots of examples of using one or the other, but not both together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got back to looking into this question again and it turns out the solution is nearly as simple as I expected.  The solution is to have two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` classes.  This is described here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

Two things to be aware of when doing this are:

1. The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` classes must have different `@Order` value.  So I annotated one of them with `@Order(1)`, forcing that one to be evaluated first when processing HTTP requests.  In my case it doesn't really matter which one is first, they just have to be different.
2. The two `HttpSecurity` configurations need to apply to different URLs.  This is done by using `antMatcher()` values for each one.  Given that the value provided to `@RequestMapping` can be an array of URLs, it's still possible to have just a single REST controller method handling requests to both URLs.

So here they are:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class APISecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Order(1)
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

And

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UISecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ui/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```