# Access restriction depending on client type – Spring mvc, spring security

Tags: angularjs, cordova, spring-mvc, spring-security

We a have a spring mvc rest api and a login controller.

This is consumed via multiple clients - mobile (cordova/angular) and webapp (angular).

We have roles (spring security) assigned to certain types of user i.e. **RoleA** can administer users in **RoleB**.

Currently in our mobile app we only support people in **RoleB**.

Is there a best practice way to restrict people in **RoleA** logging in on the mobile app while still keeping their current access level on the webapp?

Things I have considered:

> - Somehow detect the source of the login request, intercept and restrict possibly with new security.xml.
> - Have a separate login method.
> - Do something client side.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I wanted to use separate security setups for a JavaScript single page app and mobile applications regarding to authentication mechanisms (cookie based with csrf vs. pure basic auth without sessions).

I found some techniques to split up the security config by bootstrapping different security configs which are chosen by some url pattern. I was able to reuse my controllers by just aliasing the `@RequestMapping`. Probably this setup could help you:

[Multiple Spring Security configurations for REST via BasicAuth vs. Session with CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610345/multiple-spring-security-configurations-for-rest-via-basicauth-vs-session-with)

For me, the setup didn't work in the end because it didn't allow to have really separate silos (a session obtained in one chain could also be used on the other chain). But if you just want to restrict access based on urls, this could work for you. For more details, see the spring security docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity

Please note the `antMatcher` directly on the `http` object for determining the chain - this is not the usual setup for the roles which are defined on `.authorizeRequests()`.

Comment: Thanks very much ajaegle - I will take a look and let you know.